# LocationParseError: Failed to parse: label empty or too long

Tags: parsing, url, jupyter-notebook, request, python-3.10

I wrote a code that performs a request for a set of URLs and stores the response (final URL), the error occurred because of the parsing of this type of URL (xn-----7kctapfjvlndvhiafp8oxc.xn--p1ai/), This is because the URL part of the domain is an encoded representation of the Cyrillic domain "купить-семена-россия".

```
LocationParseError: Failed to parse: '%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f.%d1%80%d1%84', label empty or too long
```

I used this library:

```
from urllib. parse import urlparse
```

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def fix_location_parse_error(url):
    try:
        # Parse the URL using urlparse
        parsed_url = urlparse(url)
        final_url = parsed_url.geturl()

        hostname = parsed_url.hostname
        if not hostname or len(hostname) > 255:
            print(f"Invalid URL: {url}")
            return

        response = requests.get(url, timeout=120)
        status_code = response.status_code

        if response.status_code == 200 and response.content:
            print(f"URL: {url}\nFinal URL: {final_url}\nStatus: {status_code}")
        else:
            print(f"URL with status code {response.status_code}: {url}")

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"URL: {url}\nAn error occurred: {e}\nStatus: Error")

        
url = 'http://xn-----7kctapfjvlndvhiafp8oxc.xn--p1ai'
fix_location_parse_error(url)
```

When I was trying to solve the problem, this code worked correctly, but on the second attempt, the same error message returns!

I'm using Python 3.10 in Jupyter

Please help me to solve this problem and what library can I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by utilizing this exception, and I hope it is useful to others.

`from urllib3.exceptions import LocationParseError`

`except LocationParseError as e: print(f"URL: {url}\n An error occurred while parsing the location: {e}\nStatus: Error")`